# Any easy way to get notification of SO questions containing particular text?

Tags: discussion, notifications

I know you can follow tags on StackOverflow, but I would like to monitor for questions mentioning a certain topic that people never seem to tag.  Searching in the S.O. and S.E. search boxes or Google with the `site:` keyword is how I usually do it, but surely there is an easier way to get notifications, for example via email?

I already use the Stack Exchange Notifier under OSX, but it only tracks responses to my questions.  I know there's a search API, but it returns values in JSON format, which means I would have to write something to process the output.  It appears Stack2RSS is dead (though I know the code is available).   If I had time, I would write something, but I don't, hence my question.

And, my apologies if this is something really obvious or easy and I simply missed it.  Please point me in the right direction if so.